# will_paginate giving blank pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm use will_paginate gem in my Rails application.

controller code:

```
def index
  @posts = Guestbook.order('id DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
 end
```

view code (used foundation gem):

```
<%= foundation_paginate @posts %>
```

Everything works fine, but if you type in the address bar room for a page, a blank page is displayed (no error messages or redirect to the first page). Tell me how to fix it, please.
P.S. I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: Wouldn't you need it to be Guestbook.all.order('id DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)

Comment: NoMethodError in GuestbookController#index

undefined method `order' for #<Array:0xb849d50>

Comment: What if you remove .order, or try will_paginate @movie.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5) <%= will_paginate @movie %>

Comment: ahmet, No work.. Screen: http://rghost.ru/45988244.view

Comment: do you have a few guestbook entries with all attributes blank? check your database, maybe this is your error.

Comment: I suggest you try will_paginate gem

Comment: I cleared the table and completely filled it again. All values ​​are filled.

Comment: ahmet, I already use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set will_paginate to use an array.

In config/initializers/

create a new file called will_paginate_extensions.rb

and add this:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

I also would recommend not to use that foundation gem you are using for will_paginate, It can't receive parameters. I ran into that problem with that gem so i made one that can receive parameters 
https://github.com/acrogenesis/will_paginate-foundation